# How can I install and run Docker CE on OpenSUSE Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, redhat, opensuse, sles

Since the "new" Docker release where CE and EE diverged from the single unified Docker, Docker doesn't officialy support or provide installation instructions for using CE on OpenSUSE, SLES or Redhat, those distros are EE-only.

I find this to be a bit of a short-sighted decision on the part of Docker - CE should be available for all platforms that EE is available for.

How can I install the latest version of Docker CE on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed (or similar distro with an RPM-based package manager) which only has support for Docker EE?

Answer (score 8):

I managed to install `Docker version 17.04.0-ce, build 78d1802` and it's running fine, despite the fact that OpenSUSE (nor SLES or Redhat) are not officially supported by Docker CE.

The solution I used was to install an OBS built package of Docker under the `Virtualization:/containers` repository rather than the Docker package from the official OpenSUSE repos (which still have the hugely outdated `1.13.0`) or trying to build from source.

You can view the index where I found this built package here:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/x86_64/

The specific RPM I installed was found at:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/x86_64/docker-17.04.0_ce-191.6.x86_64.rpm.mirrorlist